# Backbone - expanded views and zombies

Tags: backbone.js

I render a collection of backbone models in a list view, where each model has its own listItemView such as.

```
 var els = [];      
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(model){                     
        var view = new TB_BB.RequestItemView({model : model});
        els.push(view.render().el);
    });
    $('#request-list').append(els);
```

Each of the ItemsView can be expanded on a click event (where a call to the server is made) such as.

```
showDetails : function() {      

    var m = new TB_BB.RequestDetails({id : this.model.get('id')});
    var outerthis = this;
    m.fetch({success : function() {
        var det = new TB_BB.RequestDetailsView({model : m, el : outerthis.el, current : outerthis, template : '#request-expanded-template'});           
        det.render();       

    }});                
}
```

So the logic is that this expanded view opens in the el of the current item.  You may have noticed that I am passing a reference to the current view (outerthis) this was to avoid me having zombies of this view when closing expanding view.

So in the expanded view we have a 'hide' method which should hide the expanded view and show the original element such as (where current is the reference to the non-expanded view).

```
hideDetails : function() {
    $(this.el).empty();     
    this.options.current.render();
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the best way of doing this - but not sure what would be the best way?  In this case there are no zombies when calling the hidedetails (as its referencing the  original view).  However I am guessing that each time the 'showDetails' view is called and closed a new zombie exists?  Could anyone enlighten what would be a better way of having expanded views of a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar case in the past where I had to render a tree type structure, with list items opening to show sub-lists and closing again. The way I implemented the solution was to have the something like this as the html structure:

```
<div class="list-item">
   <div class="handle closed" />
   <span><%= title %></span>
   <div class="sub-list" />
</div>
```

So each list item was rendered with an empty element for the sub view. Then in the click handler I would check if this list-item already has created a view for the sub-list, if yes just show the sub-list element; if not, create sub list view, which renders ajax-loader.gif and call collection.fetch to fetch data.

So my recommendation is to use separate dom elements, create subviews lazily and just hide the dom element when you close something, keeping a reference to the view.